# Add new user and user bio at same time

Tags: users, author

Note this is not referring to any type of author bio *display* but rather how it's entered via the Admin.

As it stands now, the new user screen doesn't have any author bio field. It's only after you create the user and then go back and *edit* them that you see the author bio and other meta data.

Is there any way to add some user meta (like the bio) at the same time?

Maybe there's a reason why this isn't already present on the add new user screen, but my situation is calling for a user role EDITOR to be able to add the user meta (bio) at the same time they are adding the user since editors do not have the permissions to then go back and edit.

I've tried adding the capability of edit_users to editors, but that allows for too much a security risk.

Comment: Did you use these plugins? Iused these plugins for handle users and there bios. [http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/), [https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)

Comment: I'll check out that first one, but I think the problem is more that the bio box is not available until you EDIT, and giving the editors the ability to edit users is not an option...